# PHP > Open File Instead of Force Download

Tags: php, download

I am trying to modify a script I purchased to 'OPEN' file in a browser, rather than 'FORCE DOWNLOAD' as it currently does. I pasted the code before.

Here is how it currently works.

1. User purchases Blackberry application
2. Email with Download link is
   clicked.
3. When the URL is clicked the file 'DOWNLOADS' instead of
   opening or executing.

I would like to make the URL > OPEN in the user's mobile browser instead of forcing the download. When the user receives the link it looks like this:

`http://example.com/delivery/ds-download.php?auth=bKKun8%2BFqpqjo56j1G5SaWNjg3Sgopah2NGf05iXop2k26SRzMlyiXaDiXmWZ2Rwd2aXaaOWamSkpGmqaWqommWUbWaonnVqanVucJWlqKaUnMVznsufk8rPccWll9bGp5Gek9HNlaqklad0zZ6RoaFhxKTPomGXzsSc0HVvzdWV0JWg2NKWmqNuiXm5hWxnnqfGosHUp5%2FDyKWic5rJz5XVl6bIyXJmY2lpbZpnZm5qb5Ccx9SXpMLXmMh1b8nZoMyol6GWZm5mYGhnlmdldGSY2aXL2JdwnZKX066h0NCRx3Q%3D&file=install`

Can anyone please help me update this so it OPENS instead of force downloading?

```
<?php
require_once('ds-config.php');

if (isset($_GET['auth']) === TRUE && isset($_GET['file']) === TRUE) {

    if (($product = is_valid_download_request($_GET['auth'])) !== FALSE) {
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private', FALSE);
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($product[3]) . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        if (strcmp(substr($product[3], 0, 7), 'http://') !== 0) {

            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($product[3]));

        }

        readfile($product[3]);

        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

---

Here is the PHP file that the download link points to. After following the great feedback below, I now receive this error when the file opens. The good news is that it is not force downloading any more. Thanks for that so far!

```
<?php

/* SETTINGs */

$url_pcmac = "http://www.example.com";
$url_iphone = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/";
$url_otherphones = "http://example.com";

$url_bb_42 = $url_otherphones;
$url_bb_43 = $url_otherphones;
$url_bb_45 = "http://example.mobi/F45/i.jad";
$url_bb_46 = "http://example.mobi/F46/i.jad";
$url_bb_47 = "http://example.mobi/F46/i.jad";
$url_bb_50 = "http://example.mobi/F50/i.jad";
$url_bb_60 = "http://example.mobi/F50/i.jad";


/* ************************************* */
/* DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING UNDER THIS LINE */
/* ************************************* */
/* *UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING** */
/* ************************************* */




function checkPhone($str) {
    $check = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $str);
    if ($check === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

/* REDIRECT IPHONE AND IPODS */
if(checkPhone("iPhone") || checkPhone("iPod")){
    header("Location: ".$url_iphone);
    exit();
}

/* REDIRECT BLACKBERRY */
if(checkPhone("BlackBerry")){

    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $osdir = ''; 

    if (eregi("BlackBerry", $agent)) {

        if (eregi("6.0", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_60);
        if (eregi("5.0", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_50);
        if (eregi("4.7", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_47);
        if (eregi("4.6", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_46);
        if (eregi("4.5", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_45);
        if (eregi("4.3", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_43);
        if (eregi("4.2", $agent))
             header("Location: ".$url_bb_42);
    }

    exit();
}

/* REDIRECT ALL OTHER PHONES */
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$accept = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];

if(checkPhone("opera mini")
|| checkPhone("android")
|| preg_match('/(pre\/|palm os|palm|hiptop|avantgo|fennec|plucker|xiino|blazer|elaine)/i',$user_agent)
|| preg_match('/(iris|3g_t|windows ce|opera mobi|windows ce; smartphone;|windows ce; iemobile)/i',$user_agent)
|| preg_match('/(mini 9.5|vx1000|lge |m800|e860|u940|ux840|compal|wireless| mobi|ahong|lg380|lgku|lgu900|lg210|lg47|lg920|lg840|lg370|sam-r|mg50|s55|g83|t66|vx400|mk99|d615|d763|el370|sl900|mp500|samu3|samu4|vx10|xda_|samu5|samu6|samu7|samu9|a615|b832|m881|s920|n210|s700|c-810|_h797|mob-x|sk16d|848b|mowser|s580|r800|471x|v120|rim8|c500foma:|160x|x160|480x|x640|t503|w839|i250|sprint|w398samr810|m5252|c7100|mt126|x225|s5330|s820|htil-g1|fly v71|s302|-x113|novarra|k610i|-three|8325rc|8352rc|sanyo|vx54|c888|nx250|n120|mtk |c5588|s710|t880|c5005|i;458x|p404i|s210|c5100|teleca|s940|c500|s590|foma|samsu|vx8|vx9|a1000|_mms|myx|a700|gu1100|bc831|e300|ems100|me701|me702m-three|sd588|s800|8325rc|ac831|mw200|brew |d88|htc\/|htc_touch|355x|m50|km100|d736|p-9521|telco|sl74|ktouch|m4u\/|me702|8325rc|kddi|phone|lg |sonyericsson|samsung|240x|x320vx10|nokia|sony cmd|motorola|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|kindle|mobile|psp|treo)/i',$user_agent)
|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE'])
|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])
|| (strpos($accept,'text/vnd.wap.wml')>0)
|| (strpos($accept,'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0)){
    header("Location: ".$url_otherphones);
    exit();
}

/* REDIRECT TO PC and MAC */
header("Location: ".$url_pcmac);
exit();

?>
```

Comment: You can't. The way browsers handle downloads is user configured, regardless of if the mime type has a registered handler. But using a mime type such as `application/force-download` or `application/octet-stream` will always cause a download.

Comment: @nikc.org. A better (and valid) way to force a download is `Content-Disposition: attached`.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to set the appropriate Content-Type and the browser should handle the rest.

For example, you're currently using...

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
```

This needs to be changed to the correct MIME type (possibly "application/vnd.rim.cod", but that's a guess).

N.B.: You'll also need to remove the "Content-Disposition" line.

Comment: Thanks the file its pointing to is a PHP file. The PHP file then detects the BB OS and directs them to the .jad/cod files for installation. ---- Your directions worked but now i get another error once the PHP file opens (NOTE: this error doesnt happen when I access it directly).

Comment: 0) || (strpos($accept,'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0)){ header("Location: ".$url_otherphones); exit(); } /* REDIRECT TO PC and MAC */ header("Location: ".$url_pcmac); exit(); ?>

Comment: @90Meatballs You need to add an update to the end of your original question.

Comment: Thanks - I added the PHP file that spitting out the error now.

Comment: Anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It's the Content-Disposition: attachment; thats telling the browser to download it.

Try:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($product[3]) . '"');
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that but it failed :( -- What I forgot to mention is the file that its trying to download is also a PHP file which detects the users Blackberry OS version and directs them to the correct downlaod.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the wrong header values;
You use:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($product[3]).'"');
```

This should be replaced with:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($product[3]).'"');
```

where `$mimeType` should be a valid media type (MIME Type). A list of this types is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) available.